# How to create these animations to the bootstrap cards? It's incredibly complex for me as I am a newbie

Tags: javascript, css, html, bootstrap-4

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/K52KK

The link has a template for bootstrap cards.
The link has cards with animations has horizontal sliding capability.
I tried inherit just the properties of the bootstrap cards to my code. The cards overdid every thing and shows on top. 
I tried changing z-index  for my header, but it does not work. Can some help me retrieve just the properties of the bootstrap cards?

> nav h1 
>       {
>           vertical-align: middle;
>           background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
>           border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
>           text-align: center;
>           position: fixed;
>           position: top;
>           min-width: 100%;
>           z-index: 3;
>
> ```
> } .nav ul  {
> vertical-align: middle;
> -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
> text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
> background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
> list-style: none;
> margin: 0;
> padding: 0;
> width: 100%;
> z-index: 3; } .nav li  {
> vertical-align: middle;
> float: left;
> margin: 0;
> padding: 100; 
> position: relative;
> min-width: 20%;
> z-index: 3; } .nav a  {
> vertical-align: middle;
> background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
> display: block;
> font: bold 15px/50px helvetica;
> padding: 0 0 0 0px;
> text-align: center;
> text-decoration: none !important;
> color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
> -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
> -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
>     -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
>     -o-transition: all .25s ease;
>         transition: all .25s ease;
>         z-index: 3; } .nav .dropdown:after  {
> content: ''; } .nav .dropdown:hover:after {
> content:'' } .nav li:hover a  {
> color: white;
> background: rgb(0, 0, 0); } .nav li ul  {
> vertical-align: middle;
> float: left;
> left: 0;
> opacity: 0;
> position: absolute;
> top: 35px;
> visibility: hidden;
> z-index: 4;
> -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
> -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
>     -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
>     -o-transition: all .25s ease;
>         transition: all .25s ease; } .nav li:hover ul  {
> opacity: 1;
> top: 50px;
> visibility: visible; } .nav li ul li  {
> float: none;
> width: 100%; } .nav li ul a:hover  {
> background: rgb(255, 0, 0); }
> ```
>
> .logo img{
>       display:block;
>       margin-left: auto;
>       margin-right: auto;
>       width:335px;
>       height:114.666666666666667px;
>
> }
>
> body{
>       background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(39, 38, 38), rgb(177, 72, 72),rgb(39, 38, 38)) }

This my CSS

> IBAE-Information Library
>
> ```
> <body>
>     <nav>
>         <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;">
>             <ul class="nav">
>                 <li><a href="#">menu1</a>
>                     <ul>
>                         <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 1</a></li>
>                         <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 2</a></li>
>                         <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 3</a></li>
>                     </ul>
>                 </li>
>                 <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">menu2</a>
>                     <ul>
>                         <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 1</a></li>
>                         <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 2</a></li>
>                         <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 3</a></li>
>                     </ul>
>                 </li>
>                 <li><font size="+4", color="white">IBAE</font> <br></li>
>                 <li><a href="#">menu 3</a>
>                     <ul>
>                         <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 1</a></li>
>                         <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 2</a></li>
>                         <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 3</a></li>
>                     </ul>
>                 </li>
>                 <li><a href="#">menu 4</a>
>                     <ul>
>                         <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 1</a></li>
>                         <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 2</a></li>
>                         <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 3</a></li>
>                     </ul>
>                 </li>
>             </ul>
>         </h1>
>     </nav>
>     <br>
>     <br>
>     <br>
>     <br>
>
>    <div class="container">
>        <!--first row-->
>         <div class="row">
>             <div class="col-sm-3">
>                     <div class="card img-fluid" style="width:600px">
>                         <img class="card-img-top" src="/Users/jeevabharathi/Desktop/test.jpg" alt="Card image"
> ```
>
> style="width:100%">
>                               
>                                   
>                                       John Doe
>                                       Some example text some example text. Some example text some example text. Some
>   example text some example text. Some example text some example
>   text.
>
> See Profile
>                                   
>                               
>                           
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                                   
>                                   
>                                       
>                                           John Doe
>                                           Some example text some example text. Some example text some example text.
>   Some example text some example text. Some example text some example
>   text.
>                                           See Profile
>
> ```
>             </div>
>             <div class="col-sm-3">
>                     <div class="card img-fluid" style="width:600px">
>                             <img class="card-img-top" src="/Users/jeevabharathi/Desktop/test.jpg" alt="Card image"
> ```
>
> style="width:100%">
>                                   
>                                       
>                                           John Doe
>                                           Some example text some example text. Some example text some example text.
>   Some example text some example text. Some example text some example
>   text.
>
> See Profile
>
> ```
>             </div>
>             <div class="col-sm-3">
>                     <div class="card img-fluid" style="width:600px">
>                             <img class="card-img-top" src="/Users/jeevabharathi/Desktop/test.jpg" alt="Card image"
> ```
>
> style="width:100%">
>                                   
>                                       
>                                           John Doe
>                                           Some example text some example text. Some example text some example text.
>   Some example text some example text. Some example text some example
>   text.
>
> See Profile
>
> ```
>             </div>
>         </div><br>
>         <!--second row-->
>         <div class="row">
>                 <div class="col-sm-3">
>                         <div class="card img-fluid" style="width:600px">
>                             <img class="card-img-top" src="/Users/jeevabharathi/Desktop/test.jpg" alt="Card image"
> ```
>
> style="width:100%">
>                                   
>                                       
>                                           John Doe
>                                           Some example text some example text. Some example text some example text.
>   Some example text some example text. Some example text some example
>   text.
>
> See Profile
>                                       
>                                   
>                               
>                       
>                       
>                               
>                                       
>                                       
>                                           
>                                               John Doe
>                                               Some example text some example text. Some example text some example text.
>   Some example text some example text. Some example text some example
>   text.
>                                               See Profile
>
> ```
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="col-sm-3">
>                         <div class="card img-fluid" style="width:600px">
>                                 <img class="card-img-top" src="/Users/jeevabharathi/Desktop/test.jpg" alt="Card image"
> ```
>
> style="width:100%">
>                                       
>                                           
>                                               John Doe
>                                               Some example text some example text. Some example text some example text.
>   Some example text some example text. Some example text some example
>   text.
>
> See Profile
>
> ```
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="col-sm-3">
>                         <div class="card img-fluid" style="width:600px">
>                                 <img class="card-img-top" src="/Users/jeevabharathi/Desktop/test.jpg" alt="Card image"
> ```
>
> style="width:100%">
>                                       
>                                           
>                                               John Doe
>                                               Some example text some example text. Some example text some example text.
>   Some example text some example text. Some example text some example
>   text.
>
> See Profile
>
> ```
>                 </div>
>         </div><br>
>         <!--third row-->
>         <div class="row">
>                 <div class="col-sm-3">
>                         <div class="card img-fluid" style="width:600px">
>                             <img class="card-img-top" src="/Users/jeevabharathi/Desktop/test.jpg" alt="Card image"
> ```
>
> style="width:100%">
>                                   
>                                       
>                                           John Doe
>                                           Some example text some example text. Some example text some example text.
>   Some example text some example text. Some example text some example
>   text.
>
> See Profile
>                                       
>                                   
>                               
>                       
>                       
>                               
>                                       
>                                       
>                                           
>                                               John Doe
>                                               Some example text some example text. Some example text some example text.
>   Some example text some example text. Some example text some example
>   text.
>                                               See Profile
>
> ```
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="col-sm-3">
>                         <div class="card img-fluid" style="width:600px">
>                                 <img class="card-img-top" src="/Users/jeevabharathi/Desktop/test.jpg" alt="Card image"
> ```
>
> style="width:100%">
>                                       
>                                           
>                                               John Doe
>                                               Some example text some example text. Some example text some example text.
>   Some example text some example text. Some example text some example
>   text.
>
> See Profile
>
> ```
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="col-sm-3">
>                         <div class="card img-fluid" style="width:600px">
>                                 <img class="card-img-top" src="/Users/jeevabharathi/Desktop/test.jpg" alt="Card image"
> ```
>
> style="width:100%">
>                                       
>                                           
>                                               John Doe
>                                               Some example text some example text. Some example text some example text.
>   Some example text some example text. Some example text some example
>   text.
>
> See Profile
>
> ```
>                 </div>
>         </div><br>
>    </div>
>
>
>    <!--test-->
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>    <script src="/Users/jeevabharathi/Documents/Website/IBAE.js"></script>
>     <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"   integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
> ```
>
> crossorigin="anonymous">

This is my html

I tried to inherit the animations of bootstrap cards into my cards. I failed miserably. The cards kept covering the entire page even after deleting translucent property.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us the relevant code, please?

Comment: give me a sec, brb

Comment: I added the codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSS property `tranform: scale` and use it on `:hover`

To achieve the "*jumpy*" card effect, you can use `transition: cubic-bezier()`

For the shadows effect, you can add a shadow to a pseudo element and show/hide it with  `opactiy` on a `:hover`

```css
.kitten {
  margin: 50px;
  max-height: 200px;
  transition: 0.2s all cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.kitten:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: 0.2s all cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  box-shadow: 0 30px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.kitten:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.kitten:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 30px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: .15s all ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/A-gray-kitten-meowing.jpg" class="kitten" />
```

[Working JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gusgxu23/3/)

Comment: When hovering, the shadow also increases in the card. Giving a spot light shadow effect from above

Comment: It worked! Really appreciate the help, Mate! How to add shadow while hovering the box?

Comment: I updated the answer - now with the shadow effect too :)

Comment: Remember you can inspect the elements, and figure out how it's made @JeevaBharathi